# Handling events in full screen mode in Cocoa on OSX

Tags: cocoa, macos, fullscreen

I am trying to add full screen support to my cocoa application and I am having a little trouble figuring out how to handle events.  I use the method  enterFullScreenMode:withOptions: to get into full screen mode but when I do this it seems that a NSFullScreenWindow becomes the first responder and receives events.  I am confused about how about be able to override this class to handle keyboard and mouse events (I could find no way to set what class of window becomes the full screen window).  Am I totally off base?  Should I use another method to achieve full screen mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to overcome this problem by making the view that became full the screen the first responder.